# Asymptotic behaviour of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, asymptotics

Let $\{p_n\}_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\{N_n\}_n\subset \mathbb{N}$ be sequences with $0\leq p_n\leq 1$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} N_n=\infty$ increasing. More over, let $M\in \mathbb{N}$, $0\leq M\leq N_n$ and $M = N_n p_n + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N_n p_n (1-p_n)})$.

How can I prove that

$$\limsup {N_n\choose M} p_n^M(1-p_n)^{N_n-M}<1 $$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Stirling's approx?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't get anywhere. I didn't know where to use the big-O hypothesis.

Comment: Can you type out your attempts?  You might want to take log with dealing with products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:
$$\binom{N_n}{M}p_n^M(1-p_n)^{N_n-M} \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{N_n} \binom{N_n}{i}p_n^i(1-p_n)^{N_n-i} = (p_n + (1-p_n))^{N_n} = 1$$